# Our Centos server is infected with some malware. It is making calls to random IP's/ Domains. How to stop the server from making external requests?

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, tcpdump

We have a CentOS[release 6.8 (Final)] server with Drupal 7.51 and php 5.3.3 and apache.

When we go to certain pages on the server, the server makes calls to random IP addresses. We traced the issue with tcpdump command. Here's the output:

[image]

In the image, the IP 45.250.47.93 is from our network while cpe-24-194-158-202.nycap.res.rr.com & 52.128.135.13 do not belong to us. These IP addresses keep changing with every request.

How should we secure our server from making these requests to random IP addresses?

Some more background:
Last evening, some of our website pages started getting redirected to ad servers automatically. On investigating we realised that some php files were created on our server and a crontab was added. We removed all the php files that were not created by us and also disabled the cron. Since then the redirecting to ad servers has stopped, but some pages are sending out requests to random IP addresses.

Comment: Shut it down. Provison a new server from scratch. Just firewalling the current requests won't make the malware go away. Unless you can do a more detailed offline analysis of what and how it got somewhere, there's likely no useful advise on such cases.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely isolate that server asap before it creates more damage. Trying to fix it online is not an option IMHO as you will never be sure to have cleaned it totally unless you fully understand how they got in (difficulty depends) and what was done (the most difficult part, even for experts).

The proper course would be to stop/isolate that server, identify the origin of the hack (eg how did they come in), fix it and reinstall a clean and fixed (or at least mitigated) instance on a new server (the hacked one should at least be formatted before re-use, or even bios flashed in case the hack was sophisticated).

The investigation can be long and should really be performed offline. If it is a VM and you can create a snapshot, do it, and use it offline for forensic analysis. Otherwise, you may be able to access the FS in rescue mode and copy all of it.

It may not seem an option to stop your service, but believe me, you prefer a downtime than to be the origin of more spreading of the malware.

Since Drupal and php are involved, it is likely to have been the entry point. Do a full diff with trusted sources, you may find new/altered files and understand the leak.

Comment: We are very sure about the entry point. We hadn't applied a security patch and that's how they got in. We analysed every file that was modified in the past 1 month on the entire file system and fixed all that looked alien. But since we can not be sure how much damage was caused, migrating to a new system might be the best option. Thanks

Comment: Migrating is by far preferable. Certainty has no price in the matter, and if you found and fixed the problem, installing from scratch should be a reasonable amount of work in comparison, or even seen as a good rehearsal for next migration/deployment.

Answer (score 0):

**I agree with everything that fab2s said.**

The random pages that are sending requests to me like there is a piece of code that was modified on that page to send out that request. Could be anything from a shell of sorts to some kind of user data extraction call.

A diff or your application against your production copy on your version control may show some leads.

Checking any logging that your application may have could turn up something.

But creation of the crontab implies that there was some access an attacker had to system. Most likely going through a vulnerability on your web application.

Checking these CentOS logs may help find the time that the machine was logged into by the attacker.

**All Users access log: /var/log/wtmp**

**Root access log: /var/log/secure**

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15117

Comment: Logs cannot be trusted when the server was compromised. I admit that chances are usually super low that you where targeted by a real genius, but should this occur, you'd better even destroy the hardware to be entirely sure you actually fixed it. As always, no certainty, just risk analysis (migrating/formatting/flashing seems low price in most cases even if it is actually useless).

Comment: Ah great point! Excuse my certainty that the logs wouldn't have been altered. I forgot the think of that.